# RACObserve doesn't give a value. (Reactive Cocoa with Swift)

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

```
dynamic var categories: [Category]?
dynamic var productViewModels: [ProductViewModel]?

var totalCategories = 1

dynamic var currentPage = 0

override init() {
    super.init()

    RACObserve(self, "categories").subscribeNext { [weak self] (x) in
        if let this = self, let categories = x as? [Category] {
            this.totalCategories = categories.count ?? 1 // Why this code doesn't work?
            this.productViewModels = categories.map { ProductViewModel(category: $0.tagName) }
            this.currentPage = 0
        }
    }

    categories = Category.temporaryInitializer()
}
```

I supposed if `x` have some value, `RACObserve(self, "categories")` will work with contain `categories`'s value. But it contains no value.
I don't know why `x` is always `nil`.

====== Solved problem ======

`categories = Category.temporaryInitializer()` shouldn't be in `init()`.

I guess `RACObserve` works fine after `init()`.

But still i don't know why.

Comment: The xcode compiler does not recognize `RACObserve` for Swift, do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

> When you assign a default value to a stored property, or set its initial value within an initializer, the value of that property is set directly, without calling any property observers.

Reactive observers work on KVO. I guess that is the reason why your observer is not getting called.